# Javascript regex space or

Tags: javascript, regex

I created this javascript regex

```
 (?<=\s|^|\.)[^ ]+\(
```

Here is my [regex fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/3mxBW2/1). The lines I am testing against are:

```
a bcde(
a bc.de(
bc(
```

See how these strings are matched:
[image]

instead of matching on line 2

```
bc.de(
```

I wish to get only

```
.de(
```

Comment: Do you mean `[^ ]` should not match dots? Then use `(?<=\s|^|\.)[^\s.]+\(`

Comment: Also, you may match until first `.` if present and simply capture the necessary string part with `(?:^[^.\r\n]*\.|\s|^)(\S+)\(`

Comment: how about adding the `\.` in the exclusion group ? `[^\. ]` ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [^ ] should not match space.

Comment: `[^ ]` **does not** match space. What I asked was if you wanted this pattern to also stop matching dots, which you confirmed later. So my first comment regex also works.

Comment: [link](https://regex101.com/r/MT7re1/1)  \.de\(

Comment: user310291 should clarify his requirements. What is he trying to do? The last line of the question 'I wish to get only  -   \.de\(' is what I answered with the minimal regex. How do I know If your answer is correct?

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
(?<=[\s.]|^)[^\s.]+\(
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3mxBW2/4). If you do not want to match *any* whitespace, use a regular space:

```js
(?<=[ .]|^)[^ .]+\(
```

*Details*:

- `(?<=[\s.]|^)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a whitespace, start of string or a `.` to occur immediately to the left of the current location
- `[^\s.]+` - any one or more chars other than whitespace and a dot
- `\(` - a `(` char.

Note that is would be much better to use a *consuming* pattern here rather than rely on the lookbehind. You could match all till the first dot, or if there is no dot, match the first whitespace, or start of string, that are followed with any one or more chars other than space till a `(` char. The point here is that you need to capture the part of the pattern you need to extract:

```js
const regex = /(?:^[^.\r\n]*\.|\s|^)([^ (]+)\(/;
const texts = ["a bcde(", "a bc.de(", "bc("];
for (const text of texts) {
  console.log(text, '=>', text.match(regex)?.[1]);
}
```